# Change language for DateTimePicker using React-Native-Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, datetimepicker

Is it possible to change the language of the DateTimePicker calendar based on the language selected in the application using `i18n`? Currently, the language only changes when the device's language is changed. However, changing the language within the application does not have any effect. While `i18n` works well for other parts of the application.
I am using this library- https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker

```
export function DateTimePicker() {
const [isPickerShow, setIsPickerShow] = React.useState(false);

const showPicker = () => {
    setIsPickerShow(true);
};

}
const { i18n } = useTranslation();
return (
    <Pressable
        onPress={showPicker}
    >
        <View>
        {isPickerShow && (
            <DateTimePicker
                mode={"date"}
                display="default"
                locale={i18n.language}  //Here adding the locale but nothing changes
            />
         </View>
        )}
    </Pressable>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The official documentation has a [complete section about Localization](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#localization-note).**

The doc describes that the system will control the **Android** and [links to official documentation about how to change it](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages) for your app.

About **iOS**, the same doc informs about one prop that only exists in iOS called `locale` but its usage is discouraged. You can set up things at your XCode project (the doc suggests reading [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-support-for-languages-and-regions)), and if you are using Expo (as you described at your question) you could check [this expo doc](https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/app-stores/#localizing-your-ios-app) (also mentioned at the Library documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Locale prop only work in IOS, as documentation say.
If in IOS the language not change maybe i18n.language is a two character string, locale props need a 5 characters string like "en-US, en-UK" and so on...

Try something like:

```
locale={i18n.language === 'es' ? 'es-US' :  i18n.language === 'it' ? 'it-IT' : 'en-US' }
```